# JavaScript - Object Length Handling and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

**My app has a SLIDER and a Toggle Option, inside a Tabbed screen using AngularJS.**

The problem is this. While the application and functionality work, when you load the page, when you go to another Tab, and come back, you can see both options on `Browse with`, and the slider disappears.

I found that if I remove the `changes.paging.currentValue` from the if statement, it will work. But the problem is this. What if the `.length` comes back `undefined` or `null`. It will throw an error.

**How should I solve this?**

HTML Code, in the Angular Component:

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs" ng-show="$ctrl.paging">
    <span class="ml10 pl0">
        <a class="pull-left f10 m10" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.paging track by $index" ng-hide='item.type===$ctrl.parameters.type'
            ng-click="$ctrl.changeBrowsingType(item, $ctrl.parameters.partition.id)">Browse with {{item.label}}</a>

        <rzslider ng-if="$ctrl.parameters.type === $ctrl.browsingType.OPTION1" rz-slider-model="$ctrl.parameters.start"
            rz-slider-options="$ctrl.slider.options" class="custom-slider"></rzslider>

        <rzslider ng-if="$ctrl.parameters.type === $ctrl.browsingType.OPTION2" rz-slider-model="$ctrl.timestampStart"
            rz-slider-options="$ctrl.slider.options" class="custom-slider"></rzslider>
    </span>
</div>
```

The problematic function in the controller:

```
  const onChangesFn = (changes) => {
    if (changes.paging.currentValue && changes.paging.currentValue.length) {
      ctrl.paging = changes.paging.currentValue;
      **...more code functionality**
      };

**....more code here**
    }
  };
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have to add here, that if you console log the `changes.paging.currentValue`, it gets returned in 2 seperate occassions. Originally `null`, and then as `2`. The number of options that we have.

Comment: Can you post the logic that tabs your page?

Comment: I will, but I don't think the problem is there. We use the same logic for all our Tabbed Screens. And we never had problems.

Comment: Can you console log the values when you change tabs? I suspect that’s where your issue is.

Comment: Well, we don't really use those values in the other Tabs. Also, we only load them after we hit another endpoint and it returns `data`. I will try to see if it logs anything. Also, will post the Tab Logic, but it will need some scraping due to how massive it is. Thanks for your time..

Comment: Sorry didn’t make myself clear, I meant can you console.log the same values after you’ve changed tab